# Deadlock on .Result from Web UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, async-await

I was reading the following topic http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

and decided to write a common utility method in my library to do a GET on remote url via HTTPClient

```
public static async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(HttpGetObject getObject)
{
    string baseUrl = getObject.BaseUrl;
    string actionUrl = getObject.ActionRelativeUrl;
    string acceptType = getObject.AcceptType;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(acceptType));

        AddCustomHeadersToHttpClient(client, getObject);

        // HTTP GET
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await client.GetAsync(actionUrl).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            T response = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().ConfigureAwait(false);
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            string message = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            throw new Exception(message);
        }
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

I know the "await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)" will prevent the deadlock in the above code
First:
My query is for "string message = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result" line, will .Result can cause deadlock or not in that line?

Second:
If I call that code from UI like this:

```
public static object DoGet()
{
    // Build getObject
    var task = Utility.GetAsync(getObject);
    task.Wait();
    var response = task.Result;
    return response;
}
```

Will that cause a deadlock?

Please note that I know to avoid all the mess with async-await, all the methods from UI to DAL must be async-await but I am not in position at this moment to change all that structure, my goal at this moment is to call HttpClient library and do a few GET operations.

So my questions is that will the above code can cause a deadlock?

Third:

Is task.Wait(); even needed in the above code?

Comment: So you were reading article "Don't block on async code", then you wrote a method that blocks on async code. What is the question actually?

Comment: I added the last paragraph for that explanation. It is not possible for me to change the signature of all the methods to make it complete async-await

Comment: @Raghav if you can't change the code to be async: don't try to change it to be async. What you are discussing is "sync over async", which is an anti-pattern and actively dangerous. If you need to expose sync: use a sync API throughout, or be prepared to spend a lot of time getting familiar with async details to the extent where you can anticipate what will happen when you call `.Result` / `.Wait()`

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for your valuable advice on this line "If you need to expose sync: use a sync API throughout,". That means, I can't use HttpClient, Right? I noticed that HttpClient is exposing GetAsync only and there is no Get method there. Which other client will you suggest to make a call to remote URL to get the response?

Comment: [`System.Net.WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the general case, you should assume that *yes*, calling `.Result` or `.Wait()` on *anything* awaitable is dangerous and can deadlock (unless you are the library issuing the task, and you understand the full context). It is *possible* that it will work OK in some specific cases, but you should **not** rely on that behaviour, even if it works *today*.

Comment: In the "Don't Block on Async Code" blog I mentioned, Stephen  has suggested that to overcome deadlock we can us the asycn method like this "await client.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);" and can use its output like "jsonTask.Result;" Did I miss something?

Comment: Can you provide your advice on the above comment too? Will .ConfigureAwait(false); save me from deadlock even if I use jsonTask.Result?

Comment: @Raghav mainly the bit where you're adding lots of complexity and overhead unnecessarily - and making it hard to be sure that the code will work robustly; there's a *reason* that coming back via the sync-context is the default, and if you *don't* do that, you need to fully understand what that means, and what the implications are. Typically, `ConfigureAwait(false)` is great for library code (that has one job and few inter-dependencies), but `ConfigureAwait(true)` (or omitted) is simpler for *application* code

Comment: @Raghav: No. That **only works** if you use `ConfigureAwait(false)` all the way through. You can't use it to "fix" a library method that doesn't already use it internally. The **proper fix** is to use `async` all the way, as suggested in that article.

Comment: I used .Result once, only to regret it latter on. better to await